# One-drive-api : body must be a string

Tags: node.js, onedrive

I'm using the library one-drive-api and trying to implement an enpoint to meve item from folder to another
here's my code

```
exports.moveItem = (req, res) => {
  let { item_id, move_to_id, new_name } = req.body;
  oneDriveAPI.items
    .customEndpoint({
      accessToken: accessToken,
      URL: "/me/drive/items/"+item_id,
      method: 'PATCH',
      body: {
        parentReference: {
          id: move_to_id},
        },
        name: new_name,
      },
    })
    .then((r) => {
      res.status(200).send({ drives: r });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      res.status(500).send({ error: e.message });
    });
};
```

And I'm getting this error

```
 {
    "error": "The `body` option must be a stream.Readable, string or Buffer"
}
```

Here's the reference to doc from Microsoft : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_move?view=odsp-graph-online)
and here's the library I'm using : [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onedrive-api#itemscustomendpoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let { item_id, move_to_id, new_name } = req.body;
      let body_req = { parentReference: { id: move_to_id } };
      let stringified = JSON.stringify(body_req);
      let b = Buffer.from(stringified);
      oneDriveAPI.items
        .customEndpoint({
          accessToken: accessToken,
          url: `/me/drive/items/${item_id}`,
          method: 'PATCH',
          body: b,
        })
        .then((r) => {
          res.status(200).send({ moved: r });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          res.status(500).send({ error: e.message });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this to work by stringifying the body beforehand.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  parentReference: {
    id: move_to_id},
  },
  name: new_name,
}),
```

Looks like its an error from the `got` library which is what your `onedrive-api` package is using. Passing in a string *should* be okay, but if not then there may be a problem with how the onedrive-api package [configures the `got` request](https://github.com/dkatavic/onedrive-api/blob/master/lib/items/customEndpoint.js#L25-L40)

Comment: I tried to JSON stringify it , even convert it to buffer still it didn't wokr

Comment: If its true that an object and a JSON string both don't work it may be worth opening an issue in the `onedrive-api` repo. It may be how they're configuring the `got` request. https://github.com/dkatavic/onedrive-api/issues